# PHP -- need to explode a string with 2 different delimiters

Tags: php, string, explode

I've got a string `$newstring` loaded with lines that look like:

```
<tt>Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp; 7th of Atrex, 3009 <br>
```

I want to explode `$newstring` using `<tt>` and `<br>` as the delimiters.

How can I use `preg_split()` or anything else to explode it?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? How did you get to these strings?

Comment: Taking your directions literally, I would expect the result to have these three pieces: _empty string_, `Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp;7th of Atrex, 3009`, _empty string_. For the sake of clarity, what is your expected result?

Comment: These strings are from a curl of a web page.  I'm trying to clean up the string by exploding it into substrings that are delimited by <tt> and <br> .. I'm new to regular expressions, etc. so I'm trying to get a preg_split expression that will do it.

Comment: Do you expect the results to have two parts thus: `Thu 01-Mar-2012` and `&nbsp; 7th of Atrex, 3009`?

Comment: I expect it to have one part...  /<tt>|<br>/ doesn't work ... not sure if it needs to be escaped or something

Comment: Explain the expected output, let's start with that.

Comment: @AndyLester, wrong site copypasta.  I think you meant the http://htmlparsing.com/php.html one.

Comment: You are trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. Don't do that. Use a proper DOM parser. There are examples at http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: Why can't I use regular expressions?  The expected output is to take a string that's been loaded with HTML, and explode it into an array of strings that looks like the one in the original question... it's all just text in a variable, no?

Comment: @JordanFine: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) if you want to know why you shouldn't parse markup with regex :)

Comment: Do note that it's just a "shouldn't" in most cases.  The other (less comical) answers in that question will give you more context.  Nine times out of ten, you'll want to break out the DOM.

Comment: @JordanFine why don't you just update the question with expected output .....

Answer (score 1):

Alright I'm on my Nexus 7, and I've found it isn't too elegant to answer questions on a tablet, but regardless you can do this using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) using the following regex:

```
<\/?tt>|</?br>
```

See the regex working here: http://www.regex101.com/r/kX0gE7

PHP code:

```
$str = '<tt>Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt>  7th of Atrex, 3009<br>';
$split = preg_split('@<\/?tt>|</?br>@', $str);

var_export($split);
```

The array `$split` will contain:

```
array ( 
    0 => '', 
    1 => 'Thu 01-Mar-2012', 
    2 => ' 7th of Atrex, 3009', 
    3 => '' 
)
```

(See http://ideone.com/aiTi5U)

Comment: Somehow it's not displaying the new variable when I try to echo it.


$newtring = preg_split('\<tt\>|\<\/tt\>|\<br\>', $curl_scraped_page);

$curl_scraped_page is confirmed to contain data.

echo $newstring doesn't display anything

Comment: @JordanFine You forgot the delimiters at the beginning and end of the regex. All the PHP preg_XXX functions require them.

Comment: The forward slashes `/` are my delimiters, though I think I'll switch them for `@` because the regex itself uses forward slashes. Updating my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
  <?php

 $newstring = "<tt>Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp;7th of Atrex, 3009<br>";

 $newstring = (explode("<tt>",$newstring));
                   //$newstring[1] store Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp;7th of Atrex,      3009<br>  so do opration on that.

 $newstring = (explode("<br>",$newstring[1]));
 echo $newstring[0];
?> 

output:-->

 Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp;7th of Atrex, 3009
```

Comment: This just says "Array" as the output

Comment: I am displaying result store in   $newstring . you want use result in program then  output value will get $newstring[0].

Comment: Shouldn't newstring now only include all substrings starting with <tt> and ending with <br> ? So if I echo $newstring, shouldn't it display them?

Comment: all substring pass one by one means all subtring store in array assign to $newstring one by one using loop.inside loop use above code  to display result.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code..

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_split("/\<tt\>|\<br\>/", "<tt>Thu 01-Mar-2012</tt> &nbsp; 7th of Atrex, 3009 <br>");
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Look at the [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org/qYVwnEZi) exapmle.

IF you want to include `</tt>` also then use.. `<\/?tt>|<br>`. See [**Example**](http://codepad.org/imFAt4Fy).

Answer (score 0):

If the `<tt>` and `<br/>` tags are the only tags in the string, a simple regex like this will do:

```
$exploded = preg_split('/\<[^>]+\>/',$newstring, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The expression:
delimiters start and end with `<` and `>` respectively
In between these chars at least 1 `[^>]` is expected (this is *any* char except for the closing `>`

`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`
This is a constant, passed to the `preg_split` function that avoids array values that are empty strings:

```
$newString = '<tt>Foo<br/><br/>Bar</tt>';
$exploded = preg_split('/\<[^>]+\>/',$newstring);
//output: array('','Foo','','Bar',''); or something (off the top of my head)
$exploded = preg_split('/\<[^>]+\>/',$newstring, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
//output: array('Foo', 'Bar')
```

If, however, you're dealing with more than these two tags, or variable input (as in user-supplied), you might be better off parsing the markup. Look into php's `DOMDocument` class, see [the docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

PS: to see the actual output, try `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($exploded); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiExplode($delimiters,$string) {
    return explode($delimiters[0],strtr($string,array_combine(array_slice($delimiters,1),array_fill(0,count($delimiters)-1,array_shift($delimiters)))));
}
```

**EX:** $values = multiExplode(array("","
"),$your_string);

Answer (score -1):

Here is a custom function with example.

http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/07/exploding-a-string-using-multiple-delimiters-using-php/

Comment: Don't give link-only answers.

Comment: [Review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887) for reasons why link-only answers aren't good.